# How to match the latest occurrence of a pattern

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Let's say I have the following text

```
bridge-domain 30 
bridge-domain 35 
bridge-domain 40 
bridge-domain 42 
bridge-domain 44 
bridge-domain 54 
 member GigabitEthernet0/0/7 service-instance 54
 member GigabitEthernet0/0/8 service-instance 54
 member GigabitEthernet0/0/10 service-instance 54
 member GigabitEthernet0/0/11 service-instance 54
 member vfi VLAN54
!
bridge-domain 61 
bridge-domain 88 
bridge-domain 93 
 member GigabitEthernet0/0/5 service-instance 93
 member GigabitEthernet0/0/8 service-instance 93
 member vfi VLAN93
!
```

I want the bridge-domain sections, so i use the following regex:

`bridge_domain_sections = re.findall(r"\n(bridge-domain\s\d+.*?\n!)", source, re.M|re.S)`

I get,

`['bridge-domain 30 \nbridge-domain 35 \nbridge-domain 40 \nbridge-domain 42 \nbridge-domain 44 \nbridge-domain 54 \n member GigabitEthernet0/0/7 service-instance 54\n member GigabitEthernet0/0/8 service-instance 54\n member GigabitEthernet0/0/10 service-instance 54\n member GigabitEthernet0/0/11 service-instance 54\n member vfi VLAN54\n!', 'bridge-domain 61 \nbridge-domain 88 \nbridge-domain 93 \n member GigabitEthernet0/0/5 service-instance 93\n member GigabitEthernet0/0/8 service-instance 93\n member vfi VLAN93\n!']`

whereas I need just the sections which start with "bridge-domain ... ending with !"

`['\nbridge-domain 54 \n member GigabitEthernet0/0/7 service-instance 54\n member GigabitEthernet0/0/8 service-instance 54\n member GigabitEthernet0/0/10 service-instance 54\n member GigabitEthernet0/0/11 service-instance 54\n member vfi VLAN54\n!', 'bridge-domain 93 \n member GigabitEthernet0/0/5 service-instance 93\n member GigabitEthernet0/0/8 service-instance 93\n member vfi VLAN93\n!']`

I know its greedily matching the start, not sure how to correct this, any help to understand this is much appreciated

Comment: Like this? `^bridge-domain[^\S\r\n]+\d+[^\S\r\n]*(?:\r?\n.*)*?\r?\n!$` https://regex101.com/r/3e2fxH/1 but I think the pattern that you tried already gets those matches, see https://regex101.com/r/gP9Y17/1

Comment: I need the just the sections of bridge-domains, see my expected output, the individual lines of bridge-domain shouldnt match

Comment: Ah so you mean like this https://regex101.com/r/WUkhR4/1

Comment: Could you explain this?

Comment: I have added an answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match bridge-domain followed by all lines that do not start with bridge-domain or an `!` and then match the first line that only has `!`

Note that using `\s` can also match a newline. If you want to match multiple whitespace chars except a newline, you can use `[^\S\r\n]*` instead.

```
^bridge-domain \d+ *(?:\r?\n(?!bridge-domain \d|!$).*)*\r?\n!$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `bridge-domain \d+ *` Match bridge-domain, a space and 1+ digits plus optional spaces
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!bridge-domain \d|!$).*` Match a newline and the whole line if it does not start with either bridge-domain and a digit or only !
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat (Or use + if there has to be at least a single line)
- `\r?\n!` Match a newline and !
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wyAj7b/1)

Or match bridge-domain and only check that the next line does not start with bridge-domain and match as least as possible lines until the first line that only has `!`

```
^bridge-domain \d+ *\r?\n(?!bridge-domain \d)(?:.*\r?\n)*?!$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `bridge-domain \d+ *\r?\n` Match bridge-domain, 1+ digits, optional whitspace chars and a newline
- `(?!bridge-domain \d)` Negative lookahead to assert that the string does not start with bridge-domain followed by a space and digit
- `(?:.*\r?\n)*?` Repeat as least as possible lines followed by a newlin
- `!` Match `!`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/olIImw/1)

**Note** that this pattern can match a bridge-domain line if it is between  a member GigabitEthernet, as the first lookahead only asserts that from that location bridge-domain is not directly to the right.